radio noise all over the 2 GHz spectrum on the Pi 3b
HW involved:

RTL-SDR / SDRPlay dongle
old linux PC / raspberry Pi 3b

SW involved:

GQRX and the underlying dependencies; same versions except for gr-osmosdr
Debian Strertch based Linux on the PC, gr-osmosdr v0.1.5
Debian Buster based Linux on the Pi 3b, gr-osmosdr v0.1.4

The following combos are working fine:

PC + SDRPlay dongle
PC + RTL dongle
Pi 3b + RTL dongle

And when I try

Pi 3b + SDRPlay dongle

this happens, on and off, for  the whole spectrum...
https://rumble.com/v59rkwz-sdrplay-raspberry-pi-spectrum.html
What I have tried:

unplugged mouse and keyboard from Pi 3b's USB ports
a dummy 47 ohm load instead of the antenna
running the Pi 3b + SDRPlay dongle off of 5V battery pack
antenna and USB cable is the same for PC / Pi 3b

To me it follows logic that both the Pi 3b and the SDRPlay dongle are in working order. What is it that escapes my understanding ?

What makes you think this is noise, and not mobile phone transmissions? (The allocated use of the 2-2.1GHz frequency band)

Where are you located (Maidenhead square like IO81 is detailed enough), and what frequency range are you looking at in the video? That, combined with https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Database will help rule out a licensed transmission.
